# Why does gnome terminal open in a strange place?

Tags: gnome-terminal

From my experience, (html, general computer stuff) the cordinates start in the top left as (0,0) and goes down to the bottom right depending on how big your screen is e.g. (800,600).

So why when I position `gnome-terminal` does it not go where I expect?

```
gnome-terminal --title="abvtrm" --geometry 80x10-0-0
```

This should go in the top left? But it goes centre right:

[image]

Why? And how do I get it in the top corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively follow the command:

```
gnome-terminal --title="abvtrm" --geometry 80x10+1366+768
```

(Here I used `+1366+768` **because** of my screen resolution is 1366x768).

If your screen resolution is (let) n1xn2; then use it as follows:

```
gnome-terminal --title="abvtrm" --geometry 80x10+n1+n2
```

This will give output of opened window at **bottom+right**!

---

For quickly finding **screen-resolution** run following command:

```
$ xrandr --current | grep '*'
```

Comment: In my answer, n1=`$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d "x" -f 1)` & n2=`$(xrandr --current | grep '*' | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d "x" -f 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of a small mistake in the command:

```
gnome-terminal --title="abvtrm" --geometry 80x10-0-0
```

will go to there - see the `-0-0`

```
gnome-terminal --title="abvtrm" --geometry 80x10+0+0
```

will go to the top - see the `+0+0`.

```
man X | grep corner
```

[Thanks @pandya](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17347799#17347799)

gives the following:

```
four corners of the screen using the following specifications:
       +0+0    upper left hand corner.
       -0+0    upper right hand corner.
       -0-0    lower right hand corner.
       +0-0    lower left hand corner.
```